# BigQuery: GitHub repo year over year growth

Tags: github, google-bigquery

I've created a table to show Github star count as of 05/2020 using the following query

```
SELECT repo.name
, MAX(CAST(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, '$.pull_request.base.repo.stargazers_count')AS INT64)) stars
FROM `githubarchive.month.202005`
GROUP by repo.name
ORDER BY stars DESC
LIMIT 100
```

I'd like to now create another column next to it to show the repo star count one year ago so I can calculate year over year growth. I'm not sure how to do this so any help here would be great.

Thank you,
Danel

Comment: have you tried to compare with `githubarchive.month.202004`? just get same query against year ago table and left join it to one in your question! that's the simplest way I see in your case

Comment: Thanks @MikhailBerlyant. I'm not sure how to join the tables. Any guidance? I'm sure it's super simple.

Comment: There are many questions similar to this on SO so don't think it's uncommon. Thanks for the help though. Will continue to work through it.

Comment: sure. agree. too many of same/similar questions - so no need to ask again and again unless it is really something unique. rather you can check those already existing posts to get the answer! But yes - you are right in many cases users shortcut that path and asking questions without first searching :o(

Comment: I'm just not sure how to format the SELECT field on the JOIN

Comment: I would recommended you to present what you are trying and what exactly problem you experiencing, so we will be able to help you on it instead of trying to answer very generic question

Answer (score 0):

Check the comments in code for how-to.

Especially important: I'm scanning days instead of months for 1/30th of the data scanned.

Usually you'll want to extract this data to a new table first, and then you won't need to scan so many GBs every time just to extract the daily number of stars.

[image]

Solution:

```sql
WITH data AS (
  SELECT ANY_VALUE(repo.name) name, repo.id
    , MAX(CAST(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(payload, '$.pull_request.base.repo.stargazers_count')AS INT64)) stars
    , '20'||_table_suffix AS date
  FROM `githubarchive.day.20*` 
  # day instead of month, 1/30th of data scanned
  GROUP by repo.id, date
)

, stars_now AS (
  SELECT ANY_VALUE(name) name, id, MAX(date) date, MAX(stars) stars
  FROM data 
  WHERE date BETWEEN '20200526' AND '20200527' 
  # a couple days to capture projects without activity
  GROUP BY id # names change, ids don't
  ORDER BY stars DESC
  LIMIT 100 # pick the top 100
)

, stars_before AS (
  SELECT id, stars, date
  FROM data 
  WHERE date BETWEEN '20190520' AND '20190527' 
  # a couple days to capture projects without activity
)


SELECT * # everything from stars_now
  , (SELECT MAX(stars) FROM stars_before WHERE a.id=id) stars_before  # an implicit JOIN
FROM stars_now a
```